# Something resets BIOS time to a prior date

Tags: windows-10, bios, uefi, time

I have a batch of HP Prodesk 400 G2 computers with UEFI and Windows 10.
From time to time, every day, the time and date reset to a fixed one, 2-3 weeks ago.
I checked and reset the time from the UEFI. Windows 10 read this time and works ok. After some time the clock resets again to a previous date, 2-3 weeks ago, the same date.
Because I use the same Windows 10 image disc for all the PCs many of them works fine but 3-4 of them don't.
So what can cause this type of malfunctioning?
I'm not sure the battery is the problem since that's nothing to indicate that. The computer is 1 year old. Could a malfunction of the battery cause the problem ?
Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, I would start by replacing the CMOS battery. They are cheap and its the first thing I would try.

Comment: Wait, are you sure you're not 2-3 weeks in the future every time you set the clock and the computer is just resetting to the correct date? :) seriously, if it's happening on multiple computers it cannot be a bios issue it sounds like some software is messing with your dates, perhaps synching to some inaccurate time source.

Comment: If the laptops are from the same batch and have been left for a period of time without being used/charged then it is plausible that the CMOS batteries have depleted in a similar time... it does very much sound like a CMOS battery problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the moment it works with these:

w32tm /config /syncfromflags:domhier /update

net stop w32time

w32tm /unregister

w32tm /register

net start w32time

w32tm /resync

The time may be out of sync with the domain controller even if it seems the computer is working properly in the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a Comodo Time Machine a Deep Freezer or any software who maybe made a snapshot of your pc around that time?

The date is stuck around 3 weeks ago, is very unlikely to be a battery malfunction, but always it's worth a try

If nothing is working you always can make a .bat file and set it to start on the start up of the PC.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376977(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I don't have those type of freezing software. Each computer locks to its activation date.